# Lucene.Net IndexWriter could not load file error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene, lucene.net

I'm building a .net core mvc application in vs code working with lucene.net and whenever I try to run this piece of code it throws an exception saying(and yes the index path does exist)

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Util.Constants' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Lucene.Net.Support.AppSettings.Get(String key, String defValue)
   at Lucene.Net.Util.Constants..cctor() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Util\Constants.cs:line 33
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory..cctor() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Store\FSDirectory.cs:line 502
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

if it helps the version of Lucene I'm running is

```
<PackageReference Include="Lucene.Net" Version="3.0.3"/>
```

---

```
SearchQuery()
     {
         indexPath = @"C:\MyDir";
         directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(indexPath));
         StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
         writer = new IndexWriter(directory,
         analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

         dbContext = Program.context;

         addDocuments();
     }
```

and the above is the relevant piece of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Lucene.Net" Version="3.0.3" is from 2012

does not support .net core

use 4.8

```
PM> Install-Package Lucene.Net -Pre
```

or

```
dotnet add package Lucene.Net --version 4.8.0-beta00005 

dotnet add package Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common --version 4.8.0-beta00005
```

here code sample [Lucene.Net.Demo.csproj](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/1fdea4e86da9fc0d0fdc3481e8548e3a457eb8b7/src/Lucene.Net.Demo/Lucene.Net.Demo.csproj)

### Ref

- [Code972 :: Lucene.NET 4.8 is in beta - and we need your help!](https://code972.com/blog/2016/07/98-lucene-net-4-8-is-in-beta-and-we-need-your-help)

Comment: Thank you so much brother. I would +1 you if I could.

Comment: Hey, for some reason I still don't have access to the StandardAnalyzer maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: dotnet add package Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common --version 4.8.0-beta00005

Comment: It worked fantastic, i got everything working!! Thanks again!!